# OSX Error dnvm: command not found

Tags: asp.net-core, dnvm

I am newbie to OSX. After following the step by step instructions from https://github.com/aspnet/home.

```
brew tap aspnet/dnx
brew update
brew install dnvm
```

I got the following error when I run dnvm upgrade:

```
$ dnvm upgrade

Error:
-bash: dnvm: command not found
```

I have tried locate the dnvm and looks like it is successfully installed in the \usr\local directory.

Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

run `source dnvm.sh` after `brew install dnvm` and try to run `dnvm` then. Preferably, put this on your shell profile (e.g. inside .profile file) so that it will persist.

Comment: Should I put the `source dnvm.sh` into ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: `.profile` worked for me. Not sure, not a Mac guy :)

Comment: I created the file ~/.bash_profile  and add the line `source dnvm.sh`. Now dnvm is available everytime I open the terminal. This works for me!

Answer (score 1):

For this specific problem like the answer above mention just run `source dnvm.sh`

If you want to get up and running with asp.net 5 in OSX see how I fixed some problems on the way [this blog post tutorial can help](http://hjgraca.github.io/2015/05/12/AspNet5-OSX-Setup-Troubleshoot/)

Comment: The article is very useful! One minor thing though, the `sudo dnu restore` gives error ... complaining about the bower doesn't like sudo. To solve the problem what I did is to run `dnu restore` a 2nd time without sudo.

Comment: A question related to your `export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=false`. Can you explain why the sample project from Microsoft  https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev/samples/latest/HelloWeb  doesn't require to use that environment variable?

Comment: @VincentLeung I had issues with executing ``dnu restore only``, I updated the tutorial and execute  ``sudo dnu restore --allow-root`` . That environment variable is a bug in Mono, there is a github thread on that issue https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2118 and on mono-project known bugs http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.12.0/#known-issues